# When Can I Use A Composable in the Scope of a LazyList or Column?

Tags: kotlin, components, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have built a number of projects and components with Jetpack Compose. I've read the docs and other tutorials, sites, and posts on StackOverFlow.

I am unclear about when I am allowed to use composables and composable functions inside of another composable, particularly with a `LazyColumn`.

I have components where I use a `Row` or a `Column` inside of a `LazyColumn`.  Other times I try to create an `itemsIndexed` list that creates a series of `Row`s or `Card`s and I get an error that `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`.

Isn't the `LazyColumn` considered a @Composable function?  The entire `LazyColumn` is within a @Composable function itself.

I'm confused about where the context changes from a composable environment to a non-composable environment.

Can anyone explain?  What am I confusing?

Comment: Look at the type of the lambda `LazyColumn` accepts. If it's not annotated with `@Composable` it's not a composable. I believe in a `LazyColumn` you're supposed to use functions like `item` or `items` that accept a composable lambda. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazylistscope).

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to make a deep dive into lambdas and lambda types.  Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

As this says you need to call a Composable from a function that is annotated with `@Composable`

If you check LazyColumn function signature

```
@Composable
fun LazyColumn(
    // rest of the params
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
) {

}
```

You will see that content is not a Composable. On the other hand `items` function use `itemContent` as Composable

```
inline fun <T> LazyListScope.items(
    items: List<T>,
    noinline key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    noinline contentType: (item: T) -> Any? = { null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) = items(
    count = items.size,
    key = if (key != null) { index: Int -> key(items[index]) } else null,
    contentType = { index: Int -> contentType(items[index]) }
) {
    itemContent(items[it])
}
```

Because of this you can call Composable functions like Column `inside` item function.

```
items(myItems) { myItem: MyItem ->
    Column{

    }
}
```

Functions like `Column`, `Row` or `Box` have their **XScope** functions marked with
@Composable

```
@Composable
inline fun Column(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Top,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val measurePolicy = columnMeasurePolicy(verticalArrangement, horizontalAlignment)
    Layout(
        content = { ColumnScopeInstance.content() },
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

And because of this you can call another `Composable` inside a `Column`, `Row` or `Box`.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped!  I wasn't thinking of `items` as its own function. That might be where my confusion came from.